# jquery autocomplete plugin does not work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I 'm trying to use jquery autocomplete plugin but I haven't managed to! I have read a lot of examples and my code seems to be right, but is not working!

My HTML code is :

```
<?php require_once 'header.php';?>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>

    <script>
        $("#country").autocomplete({
            source: "country_autocomplete.php",
            autoFocus: true
        });

    </script>
</head> 
<body>



<form action="" method="post" >
<ul>
    <li>
        <label> E-mail:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="uemail"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Phone:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="uphonenum"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Firstname:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="ufname"  size="60%"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label> Last name:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="ulastname"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Country:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="ucountry"  id="country" size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> State or Province:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="state"  id="ustate"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> City:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="ucity" id="city"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Post-code:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="upostcode" id="postcode" size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Adress 1*:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="uadrr1"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Adress 2:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="uadrr2"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Compagny name:</label><input class="fr" type="text" name="ucompanyname"  size="60%"/>
    </li>
    <li style="background-color: #000;">
        <input class="fr" type="submit" name="submitpwd" style="width: auto;"  value="Update"/>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



<?php require_once 'footer.php';?>       

</body>
</html>
```

My country_autocomplete.php file is :

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pswd');
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');

if (isset($_GET['term'])){


    try {
          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";port=8889;dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
          $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT country.name FROM country WHERE country.name LIKE :term');
          $stmt->execute(array('term' => $_GET['term'].'%'));

          $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

          if ( count($result) ) {
            foreach($result as $row) {
              echo json_encode($row);
            }  
          } else {
            echo "No rows returned.";
          }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
}


?>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong??

Comment: Where are the script references to jQuery and jQueryUI?

Comment: all necessary includes are in header.php

Comment: Please define "not working". Also, you tagged the question with "MySQL", is the issue really with MySQL (in other words, is the SQL query really *not* returning the exepected rows)?

Comment: Not working means that when I type a letter nothing comes up, for example if I  type "gr" I want to see Grenada, Greece, Greenland, but I 'm not! I tagged "MySQL" because I use database entrys to get my results..I tried this with a, filled by me, table and it works..The connection to my db works fine and if I try to echo results in page is ok, but I think the problem is with if(isset($_GET['term']))

Comment: You need to show us headers.php too, if you want us to be sure you did it all correctly.

Comment: Why not just use [this](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector) for autocomplete and not have to worry about country autocomplete ever again?

Comment: Try putting all `$row`s inside an array and `json_encode` that rather than each `$row` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your php is outputting an array of strings or an array of objects of form {label: *label*, value: *value*}.  (Also, your markup as presented above is not well formed, but I'm guessing something just wasn't pasted.)  Try something like this (not tested):

```
if ( count($result) ) {
        echo json_encode($result);  
      }
```

Comment: @OlgaAnastasiadou What is the exact output of your php script? If it outputs something correct, could you check the content-type of the page?